# java - selecting all objects in a frame

Tags: java, user-interface, collections

i have this:

```
jLabel1.setBorder(null);
jLabel2.setBorder(null);
jLabel3.setBorder(null);
jLabel4.setBorder(null);
jLabel5.setBorder(null);
jLabel6.setBorder(null);
```

i want to make it simpler and less noob... any ideas?

Comment: A JLabel doesn't have Borders by default, so you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Component[] components = frame.getContentPane().getComponents();
for (Component component : components) {
   if (component instanceof JComponent) {
       ((JComponent) component).setBorder(null);
   }
}
```

If you want only `JLabel`s, not all components to have a null border, change the `instanceof` check and the cast to `JLabel`

To include the comment on your answer by camickr, a `JLabel` doesn't have a border by default, so you don't have to do anything. You should do this only in case you have assigned a border at some point and want to get rid of it.

Comment: thank you, that will certainly work! i do have borders, i didn't want to write out all the components by hand.